# How to use Stack Snippet

Tags: support, stack-snippets

I pasted the HTML and JavaScript code into a Stack Snippet but I can't run it.
N.B. I'm calling my JavaScript functions In the HTML code using  tags.
How can I make it work?

**EDIT:** As suggested, I put all the script code into the JavaScript box and it works. The problem was that the Stack snippet fills the JS code at the end of the HTML file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

JavaScript code in Stack Snippets is placed at the end of the HTML document, so when you call `init()`, the `init` function isn't defined yet.