# Stack snippet not loading JS library?

Tags: discussion

I'm new to using stack snippets (and JS in general) but the example in [my SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258607/jquery-set-droppable-based-on-async-call) works perfectly on [JSFiddle example code](http://jsfiddle.net/BYsnc/), and not on Stack Overflow. I initially thought it was due to the placement of the jQuery library call inside the snippet but I'm not sure that's the case because it seems like intended behavior [per this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339359/1634753).

How can I troubleshoot a stack snippet?

<sub>This is tagged as a discussion because I believe the problem is an error on my end, not a bug in SO.</sub>

Comment: Strangely enough if I debug that JSFiddle I get the same error but the fiddle still works ....

Comment: @rene it's about the UI library of jQuery loaded automatically withing the jsfiddle unlike the snippet here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the jQuery UI, it's not loaded by default within the stack snippet unlike in jsfiddle:

[image]

Here is you snippet working fine when loading jQuery UI

```js
$('#floor').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit'
});

$('#drag').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function(){
        $(this).draggable('option','revert','invalid');
    }
});

$('#drag').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
    }
});
```

```css
#other { display:inline-block; width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid silver; background-color:whitesmoke; padding:10px; }

#drag { display:inline-block; width:80px; height:30px; border:1px solid silver; background-color:white; }

#floor { display:inline-block; width:100px; height:100px; border:1px solid silver; background-color:yellow; padding:10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="drag" class="ui-widget-content" onmousedown="shift('drag')">drag me</div>

<div id="container">
    <div id="floor">foo</div>
    <div id="other">bar</div>
</div>
```